# How to make dynamic strong params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am starting a project in which I am trying to have the least possible effort in the evolution, one of the points is the **strong params** that must be inserted in the Controller.

With that, I created a generic method that allows all parameters, followed below:

```
@resource_params ||= params.require(resource_name.to_sym).permit!
```

The problem is this: If I want some of the model's parameters not to be used (including nested parameters) is there any way to do that other than just overriding the method and adding all the allowed parameters manually?

The application is being born in Rails 6, but the idea is some solution that theoretically serves for past and future versions.
Has anyone had the same feeling of using something that really facilitates that part of the process?
This became a problem from the moment I imagined someone passing created_at and updated_at in the parameters and changing these timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use except

```
 params.require(resource_name.to_sym).except(created_at, updated_at, ...)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But with this format I can't add exceptions to any nested and I can't even make this method dynamic